# Comparing the integer using IF condition in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I'm working on some bash script in linux i just want to compare two number. One is disk size and another one is limit. I get the disk size by using linux cmd and store it in a variable as shown below,

```
declare -i output    
output= df -h | grep /beep/data| awk '{ printf ("%d",$5)}'    
echo "$output" # Got 80 here

limit = 80


if  [ $output -eq $limit ];
then
fi
```

On running I got the below error:

```
line 27: [: -eq: unary operator expected"
```

Comment: Was this the exact code that you ran? Does not look like you would have crossed the second line

Comment: Your `df` line looks good as I can confirm from my test result Are you sure you don't have spaces around `=` in the original code.

Comment: Why trouble copying and pasting the actual code?

Comment: @sjsam: Even the `df` line has space after`=`and also he has not put his command inside `$()`

Comment: @Fazlin : I updated that in my answer, thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
output= df -h | grep /beep/data| awk '{ printf ("%d",$5)}'
```

should be

```
output="$(df -h | grep /beep/data| awk '{ printf ("%d",$5)}')"
#Used command substitution in the previous step
```

Also

```
limit = 80
```

should be

```
limit=80 # no spaces around =, check all your variables for this
```

---

<sup>**Sidenote**:Check [[ command substitution ]](https://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) and use [[ shellcheck ]](http://shellcheck.net) to check script issues</sup>

Comment: actually no space only i pasted here wrongly now i changed tat but even though im getting same error. Instead comparing variable if i pass integer condition is working like if [ 80 -eq 80] this is working fine for me

Comment: @Gan : Actually you might have other issues with the script, check the edited answer and do peep at the links given in the sidenotes :)

Answer (score 3):

In BASH, it is unnecessary to declare variables before using it, you can declare and assign values on the fly, so the first line (declare -i) can be removed.

If you want to get the used percent, 'df' has an option to do that (man df for more info).
After, with 'grep', you can get only the number with that regexp, note I use only two comands instead three you use in your first approach.

```
$ df --output=pcent /beep/data | grep -Eo '[0-9]+'
```

Also, for catching the output of a command and put inside of a variable use:

```
var1=$(put your command with params here)
```

Therefore, the first line would be:

```
output=$(df --output=pcent /beep/data | grep -Eo '[0-9]+')
echo "${output}"
```

In BASH, there can be no spaces between the equal symbol, the name of the variable and the assigned value.

```
limit=80
```

Finally, for comparing integers use double parenthesis and variables without '$' to make the comparison, instead double brackets.

```
if (( output >= limit )); then
    echo 'output is greater or equal than limit'
fi
```

You can use for comparing:

```
==  Equal to
!=  Not equal
>   Greater than
<   Less than
>=  Greater or equal
<=  Less or equal
```

Comment: Is there any problem with the original approach btw?

Comment: for comparing integers use: (( var1 == value )) , more information on: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide . Also, remove spaces in: limit=80

Comment: Although this code may be help to solve the problem,
providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.